# linux 'at' command like functionality for mysql database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, at-job

I need to update a particular field in the database based on some timestamps in the same table. Now are there time based triggers which can be scripted to look at the value and do things? much like the linux 'at' command.

I know one way is to execute a script using the at command. I am asking about something at the database level itself.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has an event scheduler.

See
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html